# Starting AspNetCore hosting from .NET Framework application

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-standard, self-hosting

So i have a .NET 4.6.1 application that is running as a windows service using Topshelf and i also have a ASP.NET Core Web application (MVC and API) that is currently running as a service and hosting itself in an own process using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices`. What i want to achieve is that, i can start the AspNetCore Hosting from within the .NET application, so i have only one process.

However, when i try it using this code:

```
bool isService = true;
if(Debugger.IsAttached || args.Contains("--console"))
{
    isService = false;
}

var pathToContentRoot = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
if(isService)
{
    var pathToExe = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
    pathToContentRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
}

var host = new WebHostBuilder()
.UseKestrel()
.UseContentRoot(pathToContentRoot)
.UseIISIntegration()
.UseStartup<Startup>()
.UseApplicationInsights()
.Build();

host.Run();
```

im getting a lot of errors. At first i thought it was because of different target .net platforms being used, but even after adjusting both to 4.6.1 and updating the asp.net core nugets to the latest versions, it still outputs these errors (This is just like 1/30 of the original length of errors):

```
    fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
          An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Compilation.CompilationFailedException: One or more compilation failures occurred:
    imlmfapg.yxl(4,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Razor' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
    imlmfapg.yxl(5,62): error CS0012: The type 'Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
    imlmfapg.yxl(4,82): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported
    imlmfapg.yxl(4,118): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
    imlmfapg.yxl(4,135): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
    imlmfapg.yxl(5,81): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.String' is not defined or imported
    imlmfapg.yxl(5,109): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Type' is not defined or imported
    imlmfapg.yxl(5,11): error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
    imlmfapg.yxl(9,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    imlmfapg.yxl(10,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    imlmfapg.yxl(11,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    imlmfapg.yxl(12,11): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
    imlmfapg.yxl(15,36): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ViewFeatures' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
    imlmfapg.yxl(26,35): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Razor' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
    imlmfapg.yxl(27,35): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Razor' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

UPDATE:

So for everybody trying to do what i did, by hosting the Web project out of a console project (both targeting .NET FW 4.6.1). It appears that the reason why this isnt working is that at compile time, when ASP tries to render the pages using razor, it can not resolve the namespaces the right way and thus can't find the proper DLLs to use. The other way works fine tho. By simply running your other functionality of the aspnet core project, with a console and self hosting.

Comment: It seems you are missing some references in your project. Read your error message carefully and add the references.

Comment: Tried different approaches from google to add a reference, nothing seems to work. Might be doing it wrong though. How do i add a reference to netstandard2 to my core project?

Comment: This seems to be similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165910/reference-netstandard-2-0-types-in-asp-net-mvc-5-razor-views-in-net-4-7-1/50186091#50186091

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to add netstandard reference in web.config like this:

```
<system.web> 
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.1" > <assemblies> <add `assembly="netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,` PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51"/> </assemblies> </compilation> <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" />
```